# Integrating MassTransit with Service Fabric Stateless service and Azure message bus

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am looking for a code sample that shows how reliable stateless services on Service Fabric can communicate with each other using Azure message bus and MassTransit middle-ware. Preferably asp.net core service.